# Vuex store and typescript

Tags: typescript, vuex

I'm curious about the way I've chosen to access the vuex store and whether or not it could lead to problems.

I've got a vuex project I'm working on and in VS-Code, when I access the store via `this.$store`, it shows a type of `any` for most items.

e.g.

```
@Component
export default class Foo extends Vue {
  get bar(){
  return this.$store.state.bar
  }
  set bar(){
    this.$store.commit("setBar", value);
  }
}
```

If, however, I import the store it will show the correct typing for everything.

e.g.

```
import store from "@/store";
@Component
export default class Foo extends Vue {
  get bar(){
  return store.state.bar
  }
  set bar(){
    store.commit("setBar", value);
  }
}
```

I've tested and confirmed that the store is modified as expected and any changed values are available from other pages using `this.$store`. There doesn't seem to be a downside to accessing the store in this manner and it has the added benefit of making the store easily accessible to any arrow functions I might want to use. Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that yes, this works. The imported `store` instance is the same instance as `this.$store` in your component.

There is a difference in usage. The view part of your component only sees the variables inside the components scope, but not the global variables. So in the first case you can refer to bar in your components view part as `$store.state.bar`. In the second case you must create a getter for bar, as you did in your example.

The first approach is the more conventional, and thus the recommended.

Now, why the type inference does not work in your IDE is a different question. There can be multiple reasons for that:

- The most obvious: The type inference in VS Code, or better said the Vetur Plugin, that I presume you use, is imperfect. You might want to try WebStorm, which is somewhat better in this aspect in my opinion.
- How hard is it to infer the type of `bar`? Do you state the type explicitly? Do you define an interface for your store state?

To get the most out of TypeScript be as explicit with your types as possible. For example, this Vuex store makes it hard to guess the type of bar:

```
export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: () => ({
    bar: null
  }),
  mutations: {
    setBar: function(state, bar) {
      state.bar = bar;
    }
  }
})
```

This on the other hand is very explicit:

```
interface State {
  bar: Bar | null;
}

export default new Vuex.Store<State>({
  state: (): State => ({
    bar: null
  }),
  mutations: {
    setBar: function(state: State, bar: Bar) {
      state.bar = bar;
    }
  }
})
```

You can read more about correctly typing the Vuex store here:

https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/5295301/Correctly-Typing-Vuex-with-TypeScript